# Can motion and or motioneye be configured to record audio with video files?

Tags: audio, raspbian-buster, motion, docker, usb-audio

I have motioneye running in a docker container on raspberry pi OS on a raspberry pi 4. I have a USB microphone attached, I want to record audio with the video files, in the same file if this is possible?

Comment: Search for MotionEyeAudio. IT is a github project

Answer (score 2):

Neither motion or motioneye support audio, so no they can't be configured to do that:

https://github.com/ccrisan/motioneyeos/issues/2447

Maybe in the future?